# Best practise: Preloaders in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, preloader

I'm a bit curious..

I'm working on an application that loads dynamic data externally - this can take from one second up to several minutes depending on the user's connection speed. Should I make a preloader at the start of the application and load in every data or make X preloaders and show them for every page/part of the application when it's loading? Not every part is visible at a single time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the later is best practice for sure.

situation:  i browsed your site yesterday, was very interested in your product.  now i want to revisit your site to get your contact information.  if i am forced to wait "several minutes" just to get your email address it certainly could be enough to change my mind, especially if you're product is website development.